# Using form_for to create Mongoid object: How to submit fields that is not model attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, mongoid, form-for

I am creating a `User` with a `form_for`. This form contains an `email` and a `auth_token`.

```
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  %div
    = f.label :email
    - if params[:email] == nil
      = f.text_field :email
    - else
      = f.text_field :email, :value => params[:email]
  %div
    - if params[:auth_token] == nil
      = f.hidden_field :auth_token
    - else
      = f.hidden_field :auth_token, :value => params[:auth_token]
  %div
    = f.submit "Send"
```

The `auth_token` is not actually an attribute in the `User` model, but should be passed along and used in the creation process like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email, :type => String, :default => ""
  ...
  after_create :build_user

  private

  def build_user
    auth_token = self.auth_token
    ...
  end
end
```

Now, fist of all, the `auth_token` gets put into the form when it comes through the params. However, if the form is submitted but re-rendered, devise raises an error because `auth_id`is not a field in the `User` model:

```
undefined method `auth_token' for #<User:0x007fd702df2b50>
```

Also, if the `auth_token` is successfully submitted directly from the form that was filled out with params, then an `Mongoid::Errors::UnknownAttribute` is of course also raised.

How do I submit fields to be used in the user model without them being actual attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add a field that should not be saved in db.. you could use `attr_accessor :auth_token`

so the model will look something similar to the following

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email, :type => String, :default => ""
  attr_accessor :auth_token
  ...
end
```

this way the user model can respond to `self.auth_token` which was the cause of the error..
behind the scene `attr_accessor` create an attribute, setter and a getter methods for it
so the upper definition is similar to the following...

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email, :type => String, :default => ""

  # class attribute      
  @auth_token

  def auth_token
    # getter method
    @auth_token
  end

  def auth_token=(value)
    # setter method
    @auth_token = value
  end
  ...
end
```

but i'm not sure if the second definition will serve your purpose or will it fail... i only use the first method...

one last thing to note: you **should not run your own authentication** use something like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or any other solution you like